# Mathematica Mac Keyboard Shortcuts not Working?

Tags: keyboard

Really I'm just trying to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> shortcut to make a radical, but for some reason this won't work. What could possibly be going wrong? The exponent shortcut works (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>).

Comment: What OS version?  Do you have Spaces enabled?

Comment: It work here, Mma 9 & OS X 10.8, US English kb layout.  What language keyboard layout are you using?  What keyboard shortcut is listed next to the menu item Insert -> Typesetting -> Radical?  Does that menu item work?  Did you ever edit any files inside the Mma installation directory?

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+@? On my keyboard the @ is over the 2. Can you try to use the number where the at is?

Comment: @BrettChampion, I'm using 10.8.2, I do have spaces enabled.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I'm using the US English keyboard layout as well. The shortcut listed is ^2. That does not work, and I haven't edited any Mathematica files on this machine.

Comment: @halirutan, That worked! Thank you :-) I can't believe I never tried just pressing Shift. I feel like a schmuck.

Thanks folks!

Comment: Is it possible then that a global (system-wide) shortcut is set for Ctrl-2, but not for Shift-Ctrl-2?

Comment: Ctrl+2 works as a shortcut for inserting a radical on my OS X system as well as Ctrl+Shift+2. Suggest you check System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts for a preemptive assignment of Ctrl+2

Comment: Useful free tool for displaying current keyboard shortcuts: [Cheat Sheet](http://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/)

Comment: @Szabolcs, I don't have anything set for ^2 to my knowledge. It doesn't seem to do anything in any other app, and nothing in the System Preferences>Keyboard>Keyboard Shortcuts pane reveals anything.

Comment: @m_goldberg, Checked it and found nothing with that combination.

Comment: @cormullion, That is a very nice app. I downloaded it. It says that ^2 is assigned for radical. But that doesn't work. Only adding Shift works.

Comment: @BrettChampion what does it mean to "have spaces enabled"?

Comment: @relatively: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaces_(software) which still exists, though is exposed a bit differently now, but which uses/used keyboard shortcuts that could overlap with ones used by Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

Converting my comment to an answer. On my OSX machine <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> worked, so I checked the documentation which states under **Details and Options**

> [image]

In my keyboard layout the <kbd>2</kbd> is the same key which is used for the <kbd>@</kbd>. Maybe on your machine this differs. Can you try to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd>?

Comment: I have almost the same problem: NONE of the control sequences work on my mac, in the cloud. Wolfram just beeps at me when I try to use them. The weirdest thing is, I faintly remember I was able to use them at an earlier time. I have an american keyboard, I checked keyboard shortcuts in System Preferences (almost all are disabled, and none of them were any of the ones that mathematica uses).