# Superscript on mac hotkey not working

Tags: keyboard, mac-os-x

I cannot input superscript with the keyboard shortcut ctrl-6.

I am on mac osX 10.14.5. The menu button in insert>typesetting>superscript works and says the shortcut is ctrl-6. One site said use ctrl-6; another site said use ctrl-^. Other shortcuts like control-7 (above) and ctrl-minus (subscript) work.  I have tried control and command with different combinations of shift and various numbers. No luck.  I haven't edited any Mathematica setting files.

Similar question: [Mathematica Mac Keyboard Shortcuts not Working?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18636/mathematica-mac-keyboard-shortcuts-not-working)

Comment: On my machine on Windows, both CTRL+6 and CTRL + Shift + 6 (= CTRL + ^) work. Restart MMA? Restart computer? Contact Wolfram Support? Not sure if anybody *here* could help much further.

Answer (score 1):

Traverse the menus of Your personal Mathematica installation. All keyboard shortcuts presented there are valid for Your Mathematica installation and Your personal everyday workflow.

I simply am able to state that ^ is corresponding von Mac OSX Catalina equivalent to crtl-6.

Many question on mathematica.stackexchange.com are from Windows user. That is no wonder since the Mac OSx version is 64bit only just since very few versions of Masc OsX and Mathematica version 12.0 and before only a 32bit version was available for buying.

There are process flows for adopting the Windows shortcuts very fast on Mac OsX but that cause trouble with system keyboard shortcut. There is a true need for the change to Mac OsX keyboard shortcuts.

Most of the shortcuts are intuitive as well. The others need to be learned either in the front end itself or with specialised learning tools.

[rebinding-keys-to-define-new-keyboard-shortcuts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7611/rebinding-keys-to-define-new-keyboard-shortcuts)
will give all what is needed for get confidence on Mac OsX with versions from 12 on.